# stack, push and pop in python

Tags: python, string

The question is to write a function that creates a stack, pushes the letters in the given parameter string onto the stack and pops them off as indicated by the `'*'`s in the parameter string. A letter in the expression indicates a push onto the stack, and an asterisk indicates a pop operation. The function is called `modify_stack`, which accepts a single string as a parameter and returns the sequence of values returned by the pop operations. Calling the function using `print(modify_stack('EAS*Y*QUE***ST***IO*N***'))`

My code:

```
def modify_stack(symbolString):
    stack=Stack()
    i=0
    for i in symbolString:
        if i != '*':
            stack.push(i)
        else:
            print(stack.pop())
```

Right answer is `'SYEUQTSAONIE'`, but I got something different. Please point out where I went wrong.

Comment: use a debugger and step through the code line by line. At some point it'll do something different to what you expect it to do. That's the problem.

Comment: you need to organize your question and tell us what you got instead of "I got something different".

Comment: Assuming your `Stack` is correct, your function will `print` the correct characters then implicitly `return None`. Please clarify the output you are getting.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we'd need to see the definition of `Stack`. But also -- the built-in type `list` is a stack. `my_list=[]; my_list.append("g"); my_list.append("a"); print(my_list.pop());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine with a correct implementation of `Stack` and the expected sequence of characters is printed.

I think that your problem is only that the results are printed in `modify_stack()` and not being *returned* as the function return value. This is suggested by the way that function is supposed to be called - `print(modify_stack('EAS*Y*QUE***ST***IO*N***'))`. It is clear that a return value from `modify_stack()` is expected.

Simply change your function to accumulate a list of the produced letter sequence, and then return that sequence as a string... like this:

```
class Stack(list):
    push = list.append

def modify_stack(symbolString):
    stack=Stack()
    result = []
    for character in symbolString:
        if character != '*':
            stack.push(character)
        else:
            result.append(stack.pop())
    return ''.join(result)
```

Now each popped character is added to the end of the `result` list whenever a `*` is seen. Finally the characters in `result` are converted to a string using `join()` and returned from the function

```
>>> print(modify_stack('EAS*Y*QUE***ST***IO*N***'))
SYEUQTSAONIE
```